# TeamViewer Unattended Access - Windows Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-connect, azure-virtual-network, teamviewer

I have a Windows Azure VM with Teamviewer configured for unattended access.

When I stop and deallocate the VM, next time I start the Cloud Service & VM, the Teamviewer is not getting any unattended access. I have once again to login using RDP to configure it.

Is there a way to keep the unattended access configuration even after deallocating/allocating the VM?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have exactly the same problem/question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you will need to utilise a reserved IP address to ensure that between VM cycles you will ensure you keep the same address.  You can find details on how to do this here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

Answer (score 1):

I guess that Teamviewer works with a display adapter channel, and not works with no display.

If we have configured and connected to VM through RDP, so there's a software based display adaper can used by teamviewer.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure out on teamviewer support how to make the ID fixed after a deallocate/start cycle. They send to me a reg file to apply in one machine using Teamviewer/Extras/Options/Advanced import reg files.

This reg file works on the first machine, but doesn't work in another, and I think is related to this a GUID, but I don't know how to use a correct one.

See the example (with fake GUID)

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer\Version7]
    "MIDAttractionGUID" = "{b71ae92c-f327-4424-955b-50d65d0709f6}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version7]
    "MIDAttractionGUID" = "{b71ae92c-f327-4424-955b-50d65d0709f6}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer\Version8]
    "MIDAttractionGUID" = "{b71ae92c-f327-4424-955b-50d65d0709f6}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version8]
    "MIDAttractionGUID" = "{b71ae92c-f327-4424-955b-50d65d0709f6}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer\Version9]
    "MIDAttractionGUID" = "{b71ae92c-f327-4424-955b-50d65d0709f6}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version9]
    "MIDAttractionGUID" = "{b71ae92c-f327-4424-955b-50d65d0709f6}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer]
    "MIDAttractionGUID" = "{b71ae92c-f327-4424-955b-50d65d0709f6}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer]
    "MIDAttractionGUID" = "{b71ae92c-f327-4424-955b-50d65d0709f6}
```

Update 1:

The Teamviewer support told me that they need to generate and register internally the GUID and there is possible to the same reg file applied up to ~50 machines, if you requested that.

So, you need to contact the Teamviewer support to solve your problem.

Update 2:

The Teamviewer support provided a bunch of reg files, one for each machine that I will use in Azure.